# KornShell script to get files between two dates

Tags: shell, scripting, file, date, ksh

Need to get the files between two given dates via a KornShell (ksh) script. If there are multiple files on one day get the latest of the files for that day.

Comment: What did you mean by two dates? Are the dates are part of the file name or you need to get the files based on their access time, creation time?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it out, but there's [a mailing list post](http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.solaris/2006-04/msg00638.html) about finding files between two dates. The relevant part:

> Touch 2 files, start_date and
>   stop_date, like this: $ touch -t
>   200603290000.00 start_date $ touch -t 200603290030.00 stop_date
>
> Ok, start_date is 03/29/06 midnight,
>   stop_date is 03/29/06 30 minutes after
>   midnight. You might want to do a ls
>   -al to check.
>
> On to find, you can find -newer and
>   then ! -newer, like this: $ find /dir
>   -newer start_date ! -newer stop_date -print
>
> Combine that with ls -l, you get: $
>   find /dir -newer start_date ! -newer
>   stop_date -print0 | xargs -0 ls -l
>
> (Or you can try -exec to execute ls
>   -l. I am not sure of the format, so you have to muck around a little bit)

Answer (score 0):

in bash shell, just an example, you can use the -nt test operator (korn shell comes with it also, if i am not wrong).

```
printf "Enter start date( YYYYMMDD ):"
read startdate
printf "Enter end date( YYYYMMDD ):"
read enddate
touch -t "${startdate}0000.00" sdummy
touch -t "${enddate}0000.00" edummy
for fi in *
do
    if [ $fi -nt "sdummy" -a ! $fi -nt "edummy" ] ;then
        echo "-->" $fi    
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

In a nut shell for ksh :

```
!/usr/bin/ksh
# main from_date to_date path
# date format: YYMMDDhhmmss
ls -l  --time-style "+%y%m%d%H%M%S" $3 | awk '{ print $6 " " $7 }' | while read t n
    do
        if (( t > $1 )) && (( t < $2 )); then
            echo $t $n
        fi
    done
```